# Decimal is not converting exponential value ( jsonConverter from JSON to C#) - mapping

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, json.net

I am facing an issue by converting JSON to c# using JSON converter. where I have a field decimal and JSON has an **exponential value** which is not converting because decimal taking it as a string not as double:

Error: **Could not convert string to decimal: 1.096E8**

```
C#    
public decimal Amount { get; set; }
JSON
"Amount":"1.096E8"
```

Comment: how are you trying to convert? what have you tried?

Comment: try this  `double.Parse("1.096E-8", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`

Comment: That value cannot be converted to a `decimal` - but it will work if you make the property `double`

Comment: Use `double` data type like `public double Amount { get; set; }` and then assign it as `var exp = double.Parse(amount, NumberStyles.AllowExponent | NumberStyles.Float, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`. To show the exponential notation again, use `string.Format("{0:e}", exp);`.

Comment: @StephenMuecke double is auto round offing value so I can't use double

Comment: @trighati I don't have to use double

Comment: Its not valid for a `decimal`, so you must use `double` (or create you own custom ModelBinder to read the value from the request and generate a `decimal` from it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I have used [JsonConstructor] that I have attached to a custom constructor of my class.

Here is the code.

```
 class myClass
 {
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }

    [JsonConstructor]
    public myClass(string amount)
    {
        this.Amount = Decimal.Parse(amount, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float);
    }
}
```

Comment: in this you have to pass `amount` in constructor every time when you have to convert it to decimal

Comment: in my answer you don't need to any constructor to define and its reusable code that you may use it anywhere just defining attribute to any of your decimal property like `[JsonConverter(typeof(JsonExponentialConverter))]` without need of write code in every constructor. always try to use reusable code.

Comment: agreed, but for using this attribute [JsonConverter(typeof(JsonExponentialConverter))] I have to create class JsonExponentialConverter

Comment: yes this is good to create once and your model become clean rather than you have to write in your model and pass amount to each time in constructor when you call this model everywhere in your project,  so tell me which is good one? i think creating class is not a big deal and its reusable thats important

Comment: also important is that, if your amount is not exponential then how your code will handle this means if it contains something like `1.096E8XX` , it throws an exception and your have to handle it, suppose your json does not contain such type of mistake but finally you need to handle these scenario also.

Comment: @ershoaib sounds great, let me try this

Answer (score 3):

If you want to convert your exponential number by `JsonConverter` then

```
public class MyClassName
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(JsonExponentialConverter))]
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}
```

This is the json converter that convert your exponential number to decimal

```
public class JsonExponentialConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanRead { get { return true; } }
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, value);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        decimal amount = 0;
        if (decimal.TryParse(reader.Value.ToString(), NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out amount))
        {
            return amount;
        }
        return amount;
    }
}
```

And call above class with json deserializer like

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var json = @"{'Amount':'1.096E8'}";
        var amount = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClassName>(json);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: @Waris Sarwar, view the answer might be it help you :)

Comment: viewed, looks great but I did it already btw thank you much :)
see my answer as well